# Hbase shell command throwing error

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I installed hbase on my VM (using ubuntu 64-bit). I could run hbase start script without any issues, but when I start my hbase shell it throws me an error.

Below are the results:

```
muhammad@muhammad-VirtualBox:~$ start-hbase.sh
starting master, logging to /home/muhammad/hbase/hbase-1.2.1/logs/hbase-     muhammad-master-muhammad-VirtualBox.out

muhammad@muhammad-VirtualBox:~$ jps
3112 DataNode
3497 TaskTracker
3869 HQuorumPeer
8109 HMaster
3278 SecondaryNameNode
8190 Jps
3359 JobTracker

muhammad@muhammad-VirtualBox:~$ hbase shell
NativeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
initialize at /home/muhammad/hbase/hbase-1.2.1/lib/ruby/hbase/hbase.rb:42         (root) at /home/muhammad/hbase/hbase-1.2.1/bin/hirb.rb:13
```

The JDK version I am using is 1.8. Path: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_91

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you check whether hadoop is running properly or not. I didn't find the namenode process in the output of jps that you posted

Comment: Yeah, it's working absolutely fine - namenode, datanode, secondarynamenode, jobtracker, tasktracker everything is running. BTW, hadoop and hbase both using 1.2.1 version. Also, in my host file I've currently 2 hosts i.e. localhost and virtualBox both I've set on 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the issue i.e. the versions of Hadoop (ver- 1.2.1) and Hbase (ver- 1.2.1) I'was using are not compatible with each other, however, when I used Hbase 0.98 it works for me.